# Saving openCV matrix to use it in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio, mat

I have a 2D object with 2x81600 dimension ,in visual studio c++ ,of which type is :

```
cv::Mat EnergyImage
```

I want to save it ,somehow , to use it in matlab. like opening EnergyImage.mat file comes from my c++ code.
How can I do it?

Comment: Save it and then load it?

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, I have process on it in matlab .

Comment: That was an answer. Save it, and then load it in MATLAB.

Comment: @AnderBiguri How can I save it?

Comment: How to save a cv::Mat is something Google can answer.

Comment: Use duplicate link #1 to save the `cv::Mat` in a YAML file.  Use duplicate link #2 to read in the matrix from the YAML file into MATLAB.